# openlayer2's popup can't be listen by dojo's dom

Tags: dojo, openlayers

1. I show framePopup like below:

   var framed = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(null,new OpenLayers.LonLat(geometry.x, geometry.y),null,**content**,null,true,function(evt1){this.hide();});framed.autoSize = true;map.addPopup(framed, true);

2.'content' is the part where I put a button by pure code like

```
<input type='button' id='showNaviDiv'/>
```

3. then , I listen to this button like below

   on(dom.byId("rcp1_map"), on.selector("#showNaviDiv", "click"), function(evt){alert();console.debug(evt);});

"rcp1_map" is the id of map.
But the listener does't work on the div of the popup .

any suggest would be appreciate.

Comment: nobody found it problem?

Comment: Please provide us with a JS fiddle so we can see your code and try to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your framePop popup adds its DOM on the page when it is initialized, you can try to get your button by id and adding an event listener **after** its DOM is rendered.

```
require(['dojo/on','dojo/dom'], function(on, dom){
      //... when the framePop DOM is rendered
      on(dom.byId('showNaviDiv), 'click', function(e){
          // handle the event
      });
   });
```